# Battery notification always showing 'xx% remaining' with Windows 7 on an acer Aspire 5590

Tags: windows-7, battery

My battery level always shows up as something like *55% remaining* or *63% remaining* ...etc despite that it is in fact charging.
Additionally it doesn't go any further than *80% remaining* even if I keep it in charge forever.

This leads me to a side annoying effect which is that I cannot proceed to install Windows 7 Service Pack 1 as its installer requires the laptop to be plugged with a power cord.
My laptop **is** plugged with the power cord but because of the above issue (it doesn't display anything else than the *xx% remaining*) Windows thinks that the laptop is using its battery and that the power cord is disconnected.

I have installed the original acer ePower Management tool that let you configure the power scheme... etc, I was hoping that this would help me circumvent the 80% issue but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the battery does not charge over 80% points to a faulty or old battery.

To work around this in order to install the service pack, have you tried to start the laptop without the battery, only connected to the PSU?

Comment: Well, I JUST purchased that battery, it is completely new but it is not an original one from acer. Why 80% though, and always 80%...

Comment: If it is not an original, it may be somehow incompatible with the laptop or damaged. If it is new and only goes up to 80%, I suggest you to return it to the vendor and get an original acer battery.

Comment: Not really an immediate option given that I bought it in another country but I guess you must be right as this is a no-brand copy of the original acer battery. It works though and I have about 2h of battery life from the 80% mark.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link](http://blogs.computerworld.com/20269/maximizing_the_lifespan_of_a_laptop_computer_battery). I had set it for Sony Vaio and forgotten. This guided me to the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.